# Induction: Prove that $5^{3n} + 7^{2n-1}$ is divisible by $4$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, induction, divisibility

> Prove that $5^{3n} + 7^{2n-1}$ is divisible by $4$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

1. For $n=1$, 
   $\Rightarrow 5^3 + 7^1 \Rightarrow 132 \mid 4$ (which is divisible by $4$)
2. Let us assume given equation holds true for $n = m$, 
   $\Rightarrow 5^{3m} + 7^{2m-1} | 4$
3. Now for $n = m+1$,

   - $5^{3m+3} + 7^{2m+2-1}$
   - $5^{3m} \cdot 5^3 + 7^{2m-1} \cdot 7^2$
   - $5^{3m} \cdot 125 + 7^{2m-1} \cdot 49$

How do I go ahead from here? I am kind of stuck.

Comment: Hint: $125\equiv 49\equiv 1 \pmod 4$

Comment: @AmirNaseri I am not quite sure I got your hint there.

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: @roko $5^{3m}\cdot 125 \equiv 5^{3m} \pmod 4$ and $7^{2m-1}\cdot 49 \equiv 7^{2m-1} \pmod 4$.

Comment: @AmirNaseri thanks got it.

Comment: The notation $a \mid b$ means $a$ divides $b$, while you use it the other way round.

Comment: $(4+1)^{3n}\equiv 1\pmod 4$ and $(8-1)^{2n-1}\equiv -1\pmod 4$ hence the summ is a multiple of $4$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To complete your argument try to use the induction hypothesis. For example, write 
$$5^{3m} \cdot 125 + 7^{2m-1} \cdot 49 = (5^{3m} + 7^{2m-1})  + 5^{3m} \cdot 124 + 7^{2m-1} \cdot 48.$$

Now $4$ divides $5^{3m} + 7^{2m-1}$ by induction hypothesis, and $4$ divides $5^{3m} 124$ as $4$ divides $124$, and $4$ divides $7^{2m-1} \cdot 48$. 
Whence the sum of the three is also divisible by $4$ and you are done.

(This is basically the argument in the comments, but avoiding the modulo concept.)

Answer (score 1):

Use the binomial theorem:
$$5^{3n} + 7^{2n-1}=(4+1)^{3n}+(8-1)^{2n-1}=4a+1^{3n}+8b+(-1)^{2n-1}=4c+1-1=4c$$

Comment: @AmirNaseri, induction is in the binomial theorem... More precisely, you can prove by induction that $5^{3n}$ has the form $4a+1$ and $7^{2n-1} $ has the form $8b-1$.

Comment: What is the reason for that downvote? None at all, absolutely any.

Comment: @Piquito the question asked is "How do I go ahead from here?" and thus asks for a particular type of argument, not just any type of argument. Maybe the DV is harsh, but I found the reply to the comment strange.

Comment: One possible reason for a downvote is that induction is not used but was specifically asked for, although I agree binomial theorem is much better and easier for this particular problem so you get +1 from me.

Answer (score 1):

Let $M_{n}=5^{3n}+7^{2n-1}$, $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Now, as you well say, take $n=1$ then $M_{1}=5^{3}+7=132$ which is divisible by 4.

So, let us assume the equation holds true for $k$, i.e., $M_{k}=5^{3k}+7^{2k-1}$, and we try to prove that holds true for $k+1$. Therefore,
$$M_{k+1}-M_{k}=(5^{3k+3}+7^{2k+1})-(5^{3k}+7^{2k-1})=5^{3k}(5^{3}-1)+7^{2k-1}(7^{2}-1)$$
$$=(7^{2}-1)(5^{3k}+7^{2k-1})+(5^{3}-7^{2})5^{3k}$$
$$\therefore M_{k+1}=M_{k}+48(5^{3k}+7^{2k-1})+76(5^{3k})$$
Where, each term is divisible for 4, and we're done.

Answer (score 0):

HINT...Write $7^{2m-1}=4N-5^{3m},$ where$N\in\mathbb{Z}^+$, and substitute this into the expression you have, then factorise.